# loss of image parts while setting pixel values to 0 and 1 from grayscale in java

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

i am doing work on images using java.
i read a gray scale image and convert the pixel values to 0 and 1 i got the output image correctly for only some images.
in others some image portions are lost
here is the code i am using to make the image array back into image

```
`BufferedImage I = ImageIO.read(new File("path"));
 SampleModel sampleModel;
 Raster pixelData;
 pixelData = I.getData();
 int[][] pixels=new int[wid][hgt];
 sampleModel=pixelData.getSampleModel();



 BufferedImage image=new BufferedImage(wid,hgt,BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
 WritableRaster raster=Raster.createWritableRaster(sampleModel,new Point(0,0));
     for(int i=0;i<wid;i++)
     {
         for(int j=0;j<hgt;j++)
         {
            raster.setSample(i,j,0,pixels[i][j]);
         }
     }
     image.setData(raster);

File output=new File("path");
    ImageIO.write(image,"png",output);
 System.out.println("..End..");`
```

size of the image is same as original but the entire size contains only a portion of original image.can u help me

Comment: What is `j1`? Do you mean to `setSample(i,j,0,pixels[i][j])`?

Comment: Have you checked the `wid` and `hgt` variables value, using breakpoints?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556).

Comment: What is `pixels`? `byte[][]`, `int[][]`, something else?

Comment: not j1 only j is used

Comment: wid and hght values are correct

Comment: i found that the probelm occurs only for 24 bit depth images .8 bit depth gryascale images work perfectly. how can i solve this problem?????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably related to the sample model you are using. The sample model is responsible to describe how the Raster is going to store the data, maybe you are using a model that puts more info per pixel and then the image gets only a part of the original buffer.

Cheers

[Update]
@Joop Egen is correct you need to use the sample model from the image in which you defined that you are using a grayscale byte per pixel "configuration"

Comment: SampleModel sampleModel;                         sampleModel=pixelData.getSampleModel();                                i have used the following code to get the samplemodel is ther any other options?

Comment: @user3133364: you need two `SampleModel`s; take `image.getSampleModel()`.

Comment: can u give me an example illustrating this

Comment: @ Joop Eggen why i need 2 SampleModel s.

Comment: i have used Image.getSampleModel() but it didnt make any difference

Comment: i have used many sample model techniques likePixelInterleavedSampleModel ,SinglePixelPackedSampleModel .But yet the code works well for only some images .For rest, image portions get lost.why this happening?

Comment: i found that the probelm occurs only for 24 bit depth images .8 bit depth gryascale images work perfectly. how can i solve this problem?????????

Comment: @user3133364 when you created you image buffer you specified byte binary and tths will wor only for 8 bits grayscale. Check the javadoc for imagebuffer and see the other modes. You will have to create your imagebuffer accordingly with tge type of image you will be using.

Comment: @prmottajr There is no image buffer type for setting 3 bytes per pixel fo 24 bit depth grayscale. what to do then???

Comment: @user3133364 You can try TYPE_3BYTE_BGR which uses 1 byte per color channel, just beware that it is "reversed" in the sense that the channels are Blue, Green and Red. Take a look at the BufferedImage javadoc here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html

Answer (score 0):

got a gud answer for my problem it worked well for all images(including 24 bit and 8 bit images)

```
 BufferedImage I = ImageIO.read(new File("path"));
 Raster pixelData;
 pixelData = I.getData();
 int pixels[][]=new int[wid][hgt];


     for ( x=0;x<wid;x++)
     {
         for( y=0;y<hgt;y++)
         {
             pixels[x][y]=pixelData.getSample(x,y,0);
          }  
     }


 BufferedImage image=new BufferedImage(wid,hgt,BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
 ColorSpace cs = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY);
 int[] nBits = { 8 };
 ColorModel cm = new ComponentColorModel(cs, nBits, false, true,Transparency.OPAQUE, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
 SampleModel sm = cm.createCompatibleSampleModel(wid, hgt);
 WritableRaster raster=Raster.createWritableRaster(sm,new Point(0,0));
     for(int i=0;i<wid;i++)
     {
         for(int j1=0;j1<hgt;j1++)
         {
            raster.setSample(i,j1,0,pixels[i][j1]);
         }
     }
  image.setData(raster);
  File output=new File("path");
  ImageIO.write(image,"png",output);`
```